# using an adequate xml datatype for c++

Tags: c++, xml

xml files are stored within a table - the column datatype refers to **xml**.

in prior, odbc is used for the database connection.

an issue is unclear:

which c++ datatype should be used in c++ 11 when using a xml datatype / column within a sql server 2005?

as ide, ms vs 2012 is used.

other issues (datetime & time_t) are clear but this one is open.

btw xerces from apache is not an option.

hopefully, this minor stumbling block (unclear c++ xml type) can be overcome asap.

edit: it is a legacy project --- the parsing and xml binding ..... and so on will be made for a few xml files (if they are selected) but outsite of the database. only minor modifications should be made within the project. the code for parsing etc. exists. the question is about select / insert a xml file.

Comment: Remember that XML is just specially formatted text.

Comment: I'd say binding XML columns to `std::string` looks most appropriate for this. XML parsing and representation comes afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after many considerations (requirements to the project, labour effort, available time), the datatype in the db was modified. the xml binding was not migrated from a file level to the db - that was never a plan.

**nvarchar (MAX)** was applied in the database.

subsequently, **std::wstring** was used within C++